# Sending email using smtplib doesn't work anymore

Tags: python, email, smtplib

So yesterday I had this bit of code written out and it worked perfectly fine, but today it's not sending e-mails anymore. Can someone explain why?

```
import smtplib

SERVER = 'owa.server.com'
FROM = 'noreply@server.com'
TO = ['person@gmail.com', '1112223344@vtext.com']

name = 'Mr. Man'
SUBJECT = 'Recent Information for: %s' % (name)
TEXT = "Dear " +name+ ",\n\nHello.\n\nSincerely,\nOur Guys Here"

message = """From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER, 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo
server.login('noreply@server.com', 'password')
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried with Google smtp, to rule out that your server is at fault?

Comment: I don't think it's our server because it's sending messages to the phone, just not my personal email.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: It's in my spam. Sorry, didn't think of all of the possibilities before I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a working snippet. I wasn't getting the e-mails in my personal gmail account because gmail was sending it to the spam folder. I checked to see if it works at my office account, and it did just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
import smtplib

# Specifying the from and to addresses

fromaddr = 'fromuser@gmail.com'
toaddrs  = 'to@gmail.com'

# Writing the message (this message will appear in the email)

msg = 'Enter you message here'

# Gmail Login

username = 'username'
password = 'password'

# Sending the mail  

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

Above standard smtp send works with gmail,
 thus it must be your server(whatever you're using) configuration that is at fault.

Comment: It wasn't the server at fault. I was using my companies owa account, the email was just being sent to spam.